# Read in a file that contains multimple "CLOB" formatted data fields

Tags: db2

Reading in a file that contains multiple "CLOB" formatted data fields (fields are formatted text values up to 32K bytes in size). 
The text includes end of line characters, so our standard import wizards get confused and think that they've reached the end of line and start importing the next record.

1. option is to remove the EOL characters within the text, then import the data.

Is any additional methods to get this to work, in a DB2 system?

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Comment: Details on version and Platform: db2 10.1 on AIX 7.1 Thank you @mustaccio

Comment: Also, are you loading into a CLOB column or VARCHAR?

Comment: CLOB, looking to find a way to bypass the EOL characters instead removing the characters...

Comment: if will need to convert to VARCHAR as the only option I will look on this option also just to make it work.

Comment: so I think to read line by line and set end of file variable ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to find a character that is never part of your data fields. Let's suppose the caret symbol is never there, so you can use it as the field delimiter. You will need to place it around each data field, then try importing it specifying the following modifiers: `modified by chardel^ delprioritychar`, this way the new line symbols that fall inside a pair of carets will be ignored when searching for the end of record.

If your import wizard does not allow you to specify the modifiers, you'll need to run the DB2 `IMPORT` command manually.